# How to access CordaService from RPC?

Tags: corda

I usually execute `serviceHub.cordaService(CustomService::class.java)` from a flow. I would like to do the same in my springboot API where there's the RPC available. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot interact with a service from outside the node. You would need to call a flow that in turn interacts with the service.